# Setting up a code repository and buildbot on remote server

Tags: git, repository, build-automation, buildbot

I have a new project that I will be working on with multiple people and I was wondering if anyone has some good software or wikis or links about setting up repository(preferable git) and an automatic buildbot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[buildbot supports git](http://buildmonkey.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/continious-integration-with-buildbot-and-git/) quite well.